# How to ensure that only human visitors can use my search field?

Tags: php, forms, captcha, spam

I am running an online dictionary giving the user the opportunity to search for a translation of a word. Now as I realized, there are a lot of search requests which don´t seem to be entered by a human. I do not want to add some sort of Captcha because this will rather repel people from using my website. So now I am wondering if there is a way to get rid of these "spam" searches without using a captcha. I know that it is not possible to completely filter the requests but I would like to lower the amount of spam requests.

Comment: This is a duplicate of probably 100 questions here (just look, for instance, at the `Related` list to the right). I'm voting to close this as "not constructive" because anything posted in response to your very vague and open ended question will just be a repeat of all those other answers. Please do some research first (starting with those other posts here, but using Google and Bing searches as well), and then come back here with **specific** questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a User Agent list/parser and blocking every bot that comes to the site... but that won't be fool proof if they don't want to be detected.

You can manually block IPs after realizing they aren't human... but that requires a lot of work and attention to the site and log files.

You can limit searches to a few dozen a day or put a mandatory time between searches... but this could affect real users.

You can require a captcha the first time they visit the site and store that in a cookie, and then check for that cookie on all subsequent searches.

You can use Javascript to create the form and inputs AFTER the page loads which will likely not appear to most bots who only read the page immediately after it is loaded.

You can put some limits on what can be searched (4 characters minimum, etc) which may possibly reduce searches.

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative to an image based CAPTCHA is to ask a question be it mathematical (1 plus 5) or plain english (what color is a black car?)

What I would do create a database table of questions and the answer to the question. The more the better.

Then when you load the search page randomly select one of these questions to be displayed to the user.

One caveat is that it is possible for somebody to go along and refresh your site many times to learn all of the possible questions. They could then create a similar db table to yours with the answers and point the bot to that to lookup the answer.

That said I think it is still a viable alternative with a little creativity.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable soultion that I know is to use captcha. You should to know there are many Captchas solutions. In other word there are Captchas that is going to be simple for the human eye. For example:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3949-PHP-Generate-CAPTCHA-validation-images-with-reload-.html